Schur complement formula for a linear operator
Recently in a lecture I saw a formulation of Schur complement formula that I am not familiar with. I am not sure it is correctly stated as well.
Let $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ be a vector space, and $T: V \rightarrow V$. We can represent $T$ in the block form
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{11} & T_{12} \\
T_{21} & T_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
Theorem: assume $T$ is invertible. Then
$$ T^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
S_{11} & S_{12} \\
S_{21} & S_{22}
\end{bmatrix} $$
$T_{ij}$ is invertible if and only if $S_{ji}$ is invertible, and
$ T_{11}^{-1} = S_{11} - S_{12} S^{-1}_{22} S_{21} $.
I understand the finite-dimenional version of the formula as stated on Wiki. In particular, assume $T_{22}$ is invertible. Observe that $S_{11}^{-1} = T_{11} - T_{12}T_{22}^{-1}T_{21}$ is Schur complement of $T_{22}$.
I can also verify the formula for $T^{-1}_{11}$ using $T^{-1}$ (denoted by $M^{-1}$ on Wiki, but I do not see an “easy” way to get it.

Sorry but I am a little bit confused, so what is your question?

@Tri I do not know how to prove this statement "$T_{ij}$ is invertible iff $S_{ji}$ is invertible, and $T_{11}^{-1} = S_{11} - S_{12}S_{22}^{-1}S_{21}$"

The statement
$T_{ij}$ is invertible if and only if $S_{ji}$ is invertible
is false. For example, consider the case $V_{1}=V_{2}=\mathbb{C}^n$ and $T_{11}=0$ and $T_{12}=T_{21}=T_{22}=\mathbf{1}$. Then, it is easy to check that  $S_{11}=-\mathbf{1}$, $S_{12}=S_{21}=\mathbf{1}$, and $S_{22}=0$.
Note that $S_{11}=-\mathbf{1}$ is invertible but $T_{11}=0$ is not invertible.
